# What causes an "Argument Exception" when saving a bitmap to a stream?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, stream, bitmap

Can anyone help me with the code below? I am getting an "Argument Exception" on 4th line. InnerException is Nothing.

```
Using btm As Bitmap = Image.FromStream(importFile.InputStream)
    Using newImage As Bitmap = ResizeImage(btm, StoringSize)
        Dim stream As New MemoryStream
        newImage.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp) 'Argument exception occurred. Parameter is not valid
        StoringFilesHelper.SaveFile(fileName, stream, folderType)
    End Using
End Using
```

This code is working without any exceptions:

```
Using btm As Bitmap = Image.FromStream(importFile.InputStream)
    Using newImage As Bitmap = ResizeImage(btm, StoringSize)
        'Dim stream As New MemoryStream
        'newImage.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        'StoringFilesHelper.SaveFile(fileName, Stream, folderType)

        Dim filePath As String = StoringFilesHelper.GetLocalPath(fileName, folderType)
        newImage.Save(filePath)
    End Using
End Using
```

Finally, I got the reason. http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2007/11/29/The-Mysterious-Parameter-Is-Not-Valid-Exception.aspx
Image was disposed in ResizeImage method.

Comment: The ArgumentException message should tell you the parameter it occurs on, and possibly the InnerException which should tell you the underlying exception that caused the ArgumentException. Post that, it will help.

Comment: According to msdn Image.Save(...) throws ArgumentNullException and ExternalException.  Does ResizeImage work properly?

Comment: `ArgumentException` is not thrown by the `Image.Save` method (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx)). And if you mean `ArgumentNullException`, then chances are the problem lies elsewhere in your code. There are a lot of calls to methods we can't see. What do they do? Are they throwing exceptions?

Comment: @Nickolodeon: ResizeImage work properly (see update in post).

@Cody Gray: I have exactly ArgumentException

Comment: Stumper, I don't see the problem.  You don't always get the correct line number in the Release build.  I only see SaveFile() as the possible failure mode.

Comment: @mdm: There is no InnerException

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code without this line:

```
StoringFilesHelper.SaveFile(fileName, stream, folderType)
```

Comment: Overload with stream also exists:public void Save(
 Stream stream,
 ImageFormat format
)